# Tomatoes at the base

Tags: plant-care, tomatoes, growth

Tomato plants were planted 4 weeks ago. Have tomatoes growing at the base of 2 plants. Shall I remove them? Worried about the stem.

Comment: A picture could help, but in any case few questions: did you bough seedlings or did you seed tomatoes? The new seedlings grow from existing stem/roots or they are just new plants?

Comment: We do really need a picture - its not clear whether you're saying actual fruits are growing at the base of 2 plants, or other tomato plants

Comment: How big do the fruits get? How strong is the plant? How many fruits?

Comment: Are you worried about the stem breaking?

Answer (score 1):

Generally tomatoes are pretty hardy plants which can have tomatoes growing in and around the stems of the plant.  The problem is that it can be hard to pick such fruits from the plant without damaging the fruits.  Since the plants are young I would remove them before the plant has put much energy into forming the fruit and making it bigger.  If the fruit is already bigger I would leave it and expect to eat the fruit shortly after it was picked (since it would likely be damaged).